# Is there any measured atmospheric temperature profile made public?

Tags: atmosphere, temperature, measurements

I'm looking for a temperature-with-altitude measurement by a sounding rocket having gone through the tropo, strato- and mesosphere, have any such results been published after temperatures were measured when going through multiple atmosphere layers? Surely some have been.

The U.S. and International Standard Atmosphere provide for [the standard temperature with altitude profile](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a8/International_Standard_Atmosphere.svg/1200px-International_Standard_Atmosphere.svg.png) of the Earth's atmosphere. This profile is from 1976 and it was corrected from the one in 1962 in which the temperature decrease in the mesosphere was portrayed differently: In the current (1976) model the temperature decreases less rapidly with altitude from about 70 km (43.5 mi) on, until the mesopause at 86 km (53 mi). In the [former (1962) model](https://malagabay.files.wordpress.com/2014/07/us_standard_atmosphere_1962.gif) the temperature decreased *more* rapidly from above 60 km (37.5 mi) on, until 80 km (50 mi) altitude.

I guess the difference stems from multiple results of measuring the mesospheric temperature by suborbital sounding rockets, possibly launched above different latitudes. I wonder whether such a temperature profile like those above, but measured by a sounding rocket, have been made public, containing at least the tropo-, strato- and mesosphere. Either an uncrewed one or such measurements may have been performed by crewed craft such as the X-15 or orbital craft on their way to space as well. Or by a Space Shuttle during reentry (measured OAT). Have any of such been published?